# I cannot understand this behavior of struct pointers and XOR

Tags: c, pointers, struct, xor

I'm working with struct pointers for the first time, and I can't seem to make sense of what's happening here. My test applies the basic property of xor that says x ^ y ^ y = x, but not in C?

The below code is in my main program, and accurately restores all of the letters of "test" (which I proceed to print on screen, but I've omitted a lot of junk so as to keep this question short(er)). The struct "aes" refers to this definition:

```
typedef uint32_t word;

struct aes {

word iv[4];
word key[8];
word state[4];
word schedule[56];

};
```

As the context might suggest, the encapsulating project is an AES implementation (I'm trying to speed up my current one by trying new techniques).

In my testing, make_string and make_state work reliably, even in the functions in question, but for references sake:

```
void make_string (word in[], char out[]) {

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    out[(i * 4) + 0] = (char) (in[i] >> 24);
    out[(i * 4) + 1] = (char) (in[i] >> 16);
    out[(i * 4) + 2] = (char) (in[i] >>  8);
    out[(i * 4) + 3] = (char) (in[i]      );

}

}

void make_state(word out[], char in[]) {

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    out[i] =    (word) (in[(i * 4) + 0] << 24) ^
                (word) (in[(i * 4) + 1] << 16) ^
                (word) (in[(i * 4) + 2] <<  8) ^
                (word) (in[(i * 4) + 3]      );

}

}
```

Anyway, here is the block that DOES work. It's this functionality that I'm trying to modularize by stowing it away in a function:

```
char test[16] = {
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'
};

aes cipher;

struct aes * work;

work = &cipher;

make_state(work->state, test);

work->state[0] ^= 0xbc6378cd;
work->state[0] ^= 0xbc6378cd;

make_string(work->state, test);
```

And while this code works, doing the same thing by passing it to a function does not:

```
void encipher_block (struct aes * work, char in[]) {

    make_state(work->state, in);

    work->state[0] ^= 0xff00cd00;

    make_string(work->state, in);

}

void decipher_block (struct aes * work, char in[]) {

    make_state(work->state, in);

    work->state[0] ^= 0xff00cd00;

    make_string(work->state, in);

}
```

Yet, by removing the make_state and make_string calls in both encipher and decipher, it works as expected!

```
make_state(work->state, test);

encipher_block(&cipher, test);
decipher_block(&cipher, test);

make_string(work->state, test);
```

So to clarify, I do not have a problem! I just want to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `char` to `unsigned char`. `char` may be signed, and likely is on your system, which causes problems when converting to other integer types and when shifting.

In the expression `(char) (in[i] >> 24)` in `make_string`, an unsigned 32-bit integer is converted to a signed 8-bit integer (in your C implementation). This expression may convert values to a `char` that are not representable in a `char`, notably the values from 128 to 255. According to C 2011 6.3.1.3 3, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In the expression `(word) (in[(i * 4) + 3]      )` in `make_state`, `in[…]` is a `char`, which is a signed 8-bit integer (in your C implementation). This `char` is converted to an `int`, per the usual integer promotions defined in C 2011 6.3.1.1 2. If the `char` is negative, then the resulting `int` is negative. Then, when it is converted to a `word`, which is unsigned, the effect is that the sign bit is replicated in the high 24 bits. For example, if the `char` has value -166 (0x90), the result will be `0xffffff90`, but you want `0x00000090`.

Change `char` to `unsigned char` throughout this code.

Additionally, in `make_state`, `in[(i * 4) + 0]` should be cast to `word` before the left shift. This is because it will start as an `unsigned char`, which is promoted to `int` before the shift. If it has some value with the high bit set, such as 0x80, then shifting it left 24 bits produces a value that cannot be represented in an `int`, such as 0x80000000. Per C 2011 6.5.7 4, the behavior is then undefined.

This will not be a problem in most C implementations; two’s complement is commonly used for signed integers, and the result will wrap as desired. Additionally, I expect this is a model situation that the compiler developers design for, since it is a very common code structure. However, to improve portability, casting to `word` will avoid the possibility of overflow.

Comment: For bitwise operations I thought that didn't matter.

Comment: I added text to the answer explaining how `char` breaks your code.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I never would have guessed it acted like that.

Comment: @DakotaWest: I added two paragraphs at the end about another hazard. (I should have recognized it earlier; I am sure I first encountered it a couple of decades ago.) When you shift an `unsigned char` left 24 bits (and `int` is 32 bits), it can overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The `make_state()` function overwrites the array passed in the first argument. If you put the `encipher_block()` and `decipher_block()` bodies inline, you get this:

```
/* encipher_block inline */
make_state(work->state, in);
work->state[0] ^= 0xff00cd00;
make_string(work->state, in);

/* decipher_block inline */
make_state(work->state, in);    /* <-- Here's the problem */
work->state[0] ^= 0xff00cd00;
make_string(work->state, in);
```

Comment: The code is intended to change its first argument. The model is that `make_state` puts the data into a working form, and `make_string` returns it to string form. This transformation should merely change the arrangement of the data, not its values. The notion is that two XORs by the same value in the working form should result in an identity operation (no change). They do not. The cause of that is not writing to work->state, which is effectively scratch space. The cause is the undesired signedness of `char`.